# php with mqsql view data I was try do view in php. But first data does't show in output. Remaining data displayed. how can i get all data in table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I was try do view in php. But first data now showing in output. Remaining data displayed. how can i get all data in table.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
 include('connect.php');
  $select=mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM user order by id");
 $i=1;
  while($userrow=mysql_fetch_array($select))
  {
    $id=$userrow['id'];
    $name=$userrow['username'];
      ?>
<table width="600" border="1"  cellpadding="1" cellspaceing="1" >  
<tr >
<th class="active">ID</th>
<th class="active">Name</th>
<tr>
<?php 
while ($employee=mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$employee['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$employee['username']."</td>";
 } 
  }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Close the `<tr>` tag with a `</tr>` inside the loop

Comment: Oh dear, on closer inspection its just a mess! Start again and this time think about what you are trying to do

Comment: `cellspaceing`? that's invalid syntax.

Comment: Nobody's paying attention to us Smokey @RiggsFolly why waste your/our breath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- Table rows had not been closed (`</tr>`)
- Usage of `mysql_*` functions is deprecated in PHP 5 and removed in PHP 7; if you're writing new code, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions. Instead, use `mysqli_*` functions or the PDO library.
- There were multiple for-loops to get records, but it would create new tables each iteration.
- The table attribute "cellspacing" was misspelled.
- The results object where they are stored can either be a resource or false.

Given these, I've made the following changes that will fix the above problems:

```
<?php

// I've commented out the connect.php file inclusion to highlight the change to how
// you'd connect to the MySQL database using mysqli_* instead of mysql_*. I'm guessing
// as to the contents of connect.php, but this should still highlight what needs to be
// done

// include('connect.php');
$db_connection = mysqli_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database_name');
$employee_results = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT id,username FROM user ORDER BY id");
?>

<html>
<body>
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
        <th class="active">ID</th>
        <th class="active">Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php if ($employee_results === false): ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">No users</td>
        </tr>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php while ($employee = mysqli_fetch_assoc($employee_results)): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $employee['id'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $employee['username'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    <?php endif ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
 include('connect.php');
  $select=mysql_query("SELECT id,username FROM user order by id");
 $i=1; ?> 
    <table width="600" border="1"  cellpadding="1" cellspaceing="1" > 
        <tr>
<th class="active">ID</th>
<th class="active">Name</th></tr>
<?php   while($userrow=mysql_fetch_array($select))
  {
    $id=$userrow['id'];
    $name=$userrow['username'];
      ?>

<?php 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$name."</td></tr>";
  }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: **Edit your original Answer** Dont add 2 answers

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: plus, you didn't fix OP's syntax error `cellspaceing`. best to catch all errors and to fix them for future visitors.